# Can not get the data from ROS Services, only entering the server but data is not out, why?

Tags: ros, python, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I need to read data ( lets say pressure) from serial Port Microcontroller by Client Request. I check the tutorial for ROS Services in Python but still my code is not giving the data value to to client. Here first the  Service Server Python node

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import rospy
import numpy as np
from os import system
import time
import Microcontroller_Manager_Serial as Serial
import Pressure_Functions as Pressure
import Modem_Functions as Modem
import threading 
import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from std_msgs.msg import String

from demo_teleop.srv import ImuValue
Communication_Mode_ = 0

def handle_ros_services():
    global P0
    data_received = Pressure.Pressure_Get_Final_Values(1,1)
    print("Server Read Data:")
    P0 = (np.int16((data_received[6]<<24) | (data_received[7]<<16) | (data_received[8]<<8) | (data_received[9])))/10000
    P=P0
    pressure = P/9.81
    current_x_orientation_s=pressure
    print("Returning ", current_x_orientation_s)
    #return ImuValue(current_x_orientation_s)

def ros_serice_server():
    #rospy.init_node('ros_serice_server')
    s = rospy.Service('imu_value', ImuValue, handle_ros_services)
    print("Ready to get_value")
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('server_node_f')
    Serial.Serial_Port_Standard()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            print("entering service")
            ros_serice_server()
        except:
            print("pass")
```

When I call the server I got this output

```
entering service
Ready to get_value
```

And here the client node

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import rospy
import sys
import numpy as np
from os import system
import time
import threading
import Microcontroller_Manager_Serial as Serial
import IMU_Functions as IMU
import Pressure_Functions as Pressure
import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from std_msgs.msg import String

from demo_teleop.srv import ImuValue

Communication_Mode_ = 0

def imu_client():
    rospy.wait_for_service('handle_ros_services')
    print("Request call send")
    imu_value = rospy.ServiceProxy('imu_value', ImuValue)
    #resp1 = imu_value
    #return imu_value.current_x_orientation_s
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('client_node_f')
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            print("entering client")
            imu_client()
        except:
            print("pass")
```

When i call the client only got

```
entering client
```

So means the server never enter the

> handle_ros_services()

and the client never enter

> imu_client():

functions. What is wrong with  the code?

Here is my ImuValue.srv file

```
float64 current_x_orientation_c
---
float64 current_x_orientation_s
bool success
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397712/can-not-get-the-data-from-ros-services,-only-entering-the-server-but-data-is-not-out,-why?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2022-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2022-03-20**:
Follow-up to (or duplicate of) [#q397753](https://answers.ros.org/question/397381/ros-service-server-and-client-node-to-publish-on-serial-port/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Client node**

You wait for a service named `'handle_ros_services'` which is not advertised in the provided code. As explained in the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#Service_proxies), `rospy.wait_for_service()` is *blocking*, and without a specified timeout it's gonna block indefinitely.

The server advertises a service with the name `"imu_value"`, which you're actually correctly using with `rospy.ServiceProxy()`

**Server node**

`while not rospy.is_shutdown()` is not needed, simply call `ros_serice_server()`. It helps to understand the difference between `while not rospy.is_shutdown()` and `rospy.spin()` so you know when to use which.

The service server *must return* a response.

---

Originally posted by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) with karma: 228 on 2022-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2022-03-21**:
So when do the changes i can enter the client but in server node never enter the `handle_ros_services()` function so Im not able to get the data. Is that because server didn't *return* a response?  How to make server return response?

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2022-03-21**:\

> never enter the handle_ros_services() function

How did you verify this? Is everything alright with `Pressure.Pressure_Get_Final_Values(1,1)`?

> so Im not able to get the data

Might have to do with the commented out return statement (btw `ImuValue` isn't the correct return type, it should be `ImuValueResponse`)

> How to make server return response?

See [Writing a Service Node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2FTutorials.2FWritingServiceClient.Writing_a_Service_Node), note the line `return AddTwoIntsResponse(req.a + req.b)`

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2022-03-21**:
I verify  with   `print("Server Read Data:")` in the function. It never print it. Yes all good with `Pressure.Pressure_Get_Final_Values(1,1)` . I only have one srv file and that is the ImuValue. Understand? I don't  have ImuValueResponse

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2022-03-21**:
I edit in the question the `ImuValue` srv file. I dont know what `ImuValueResponse` srv file should contain. Any help?

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2022-03-21**:\

> only have one srv file and that is the ImuValue. Understand? I don't have ImuValueResponse

`ImuValueResponse` is auto-generated :) See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#:%7E:text=rospy%20converts%20these,my_package.srv.FooResponse)

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2022-03-21**:
ok when do that with f`rom demo_teleop.srv import ImuValue,ImuResponse` i got error `ImportError: cannot import name 'ImuResponse' from`

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2022-03-21**:
Still not able to enter the `handle_ros_services()`. I generated `ImuValueResponse` but still no data returned and not entering `handle_ros_services()`

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2022-03-21**:
The problem remain Im not able to enter the function `handle_ros_services`. Why?